# How to use delayed_job to delay a controller action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

How can I implement delayed_job gem to this action/actions? It gets plist from an API and inserts those values to database. I just want it insert datas as a background process...

```
def get_videos_from_outer(page=params[:page], kid=params[:kid], totalCount="")

        @videos = Video.where(program_id: params[:p_id])
        @program = Program.find(params[:p_id])

        @fetch = Typhoeus::Request.post("URL", :params => {:commandtype=>"getprogramepisodes", :feedtype=>"plist",:id=>kid.to_i, :page=>page.to_i})
        @plist = Plist::parse_xml(@fetch.body.force_encoding 'utf-8')



          @totalCount = @plist.second.first['totalCount']

          if !totalCount.blank?
            @totalCount = totalCount
          end
        import_outer_videos(@plist, kid, page.to_i, @totalCount.to_i)

  end
```

And the `import_outer_videos` method.

```
private

def import_outer_videos(plist, kid, page, totalCount)

         @totalCount = totalCount

        plist.second.each_with_index do |t, i| 
        # First page has odd data and here we're getting rid off them
                if page.to_i==1
                   if i > 0
                   @new = Video.create(:thumb_path=>t['tnPath'], :vid=>t['id'], :title=>t['title'], :type=>t['type'], :kid=>kid, :program_id=>@program.id)

                    end
                else
                  @new = Video.create(:thumb_path=>t['tnPath'], :vid=>t['id'], :title=>t['title'], :type=>t['type'], :kid=>kid, :program_id=>@program.id)       

                end

        end

        if page.to_i < (@totalCount.to_i/20) + 1
        page = page.to_i + 1 

        get_videos_from_outer(page.to_i, kid.to_i, @totalCount)
        else
          redirect_to :action=>"index", :p_id=>params[:p_id]
        end

          if @new.errors.blank?
          flash[:notice]="#{@totalCount} videos has been transfered."
          else
            flash[:notice]="No new video."
          end
end
```

Comment: An easy solution could be the delayed_job gem. https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job Usage: object.delay(:options => ....).method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create `app/workers/my_job.rb`, with something like:

```
class MyJob < Struct.new(:p1, :p2)
  def perform
    # put all your hard work here.
    # APIClass.get_videos_from_outer(p1, p2)
    # or something.
  end
end
```

Then call it with:

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue(MyJob.new(foo, bar), 0, 2.hours.from_now)
```

or something.

[This might be useful.](http://railscasts.com/episodes/171-delayed-job)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As you might see, my methods loop through each other until a conditional statement applies. Will my methods be able to trigger eachother inside that job file?

Comment: Sure. You can either move these methods into the Job class, or if they're class methods then call them on their Class, if they're instance methods, pass the object id as a parameter.

Comment: Should my methods be inside perform action? I didn't know nested actions are possible? :|

Comment: You can put them in the Job class and call them from `perform`, or just call them from wherever they are now.

Comment: Haha, you're welcome. The docs are pretty terse for DJ, but it's easy and powerful once you know what you're doing.

Comment: Yeah that's correct. By the way, you might consider to add an additional info to your answer for future searchers. Worker file must be required in the controller :)